# Bidirectional binding between ObjectProperty<Double> and DoubleProperty

Tags: java, javafx, binding, javafx-8

Is there any built-in function to create a bidirectional binding between `DoubleProperty` and `ObjectProperty<Double>`?

For one direction binding it is pretty easy :

```
public void bindBidirectional(DoubleProperty doubleProperty, ObjectProperty<Double> doubleObjectProperty){
    doubleProperty.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> doubleObjectProperty.get(), doubleObjectProperty));
}
```

but since `Bindings.createDoubleBinging` returns `Binding`, not `Property` I can't use it for bidirectional binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
doubleObjectProperty().bindBidirectional(doubleProperty.asObject());
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :)